# In any triangle $\triangle ABC$, show that $4R\sin(\frac{A}{2})\sin(\frac{B}{2})\sin(\frac{C}{2})=r$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

This is a problem problem I found in a JEE examination prep textbook, it was a "starred" question which I believe implies that it is more challenging than usual. It goes as follows:

> In any triangle $\triangle ABC$, show that $$4R\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)=r$$
> Hint: $$2R^2\sin\left(A\right)\sin\left(B\right)\sin\left(C\right)=\Delta$$

Here is my attempt at it. I want to know if this is correct and if there any better alternative approaches to achieve the same result, please do share them!

We know that:

$$\Delta=rs$$

Using the given hint:

$$2R^2\sin\left(A\right)\sin\left(B\right)\sin\left(C\right)=rs$$

$$16R^2\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)=r\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)$$

$$16R\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)=r\left(\sin\left(A\right)+\sin\left(B\right)+\sin\left(C\right)\right)$$

Now, focusing on the equation of the right hand side for a bit, we know that:

$$A+B+C=\pi$$

$$\frac{A+B}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{C}{2}$$

$$\sin\left(A\right)+\sin\left(B\right)+\sin\left(C\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$

$$2\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\right)$$

$$4\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$

Now substituting this back into the original problem:

$$16R\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)=\left(4r\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\right]$$

And that gives us:

$$4R\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)=r$$

Comment: Are $r$ and $R$ the in-radius and out-radius? And what are $\Delta$ and $s?$

Comment: $r$ is the inradius, $R$ is the circumradius, $\Delta$ is the area of the triangle and $s$ is its semi-perimeter @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Is $s=R(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)$ a known result?

Comment: I recommend using `\left(\frac A2\right)` for readability. So you get: $$\sin\left(\frac A2\right)$$ and the expressions become easier to read with the larger parens. Or you can leave them out: $$\sin\frac C2$$

Comment: I'm not sure if its known but $\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ can be written as $\frac{(2R)[(sinA)+(sinB)+(sinC)]}{2}$ via Sine Law which then simplifies to the results above

Comment: Ah, the error is you have $\sin A\sin B\sin C$ on the left side when you meant $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm not sure I understand. Which error are you referring to?

Comment: @Goku This line: $\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)=2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})+2\sin(\frac{C}{2})\cos(\frac{C}{2})$

Comment: The third line after "Now focusing" has the wrong left side.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for pointing that out @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes it is, because $a=2R\sin A$ etc.

Comment: Other than that, it looks fine. I would reference the law of sines step more explicitly. I personally know law of sines as $\sin A/a =\sin B/b =\sin C/c,$ and had forgotten the relation to the circumcenter radius. It's not hard to prove $a=2R\sin A,$ I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, $O$ is the circumcenter of $\Delta ABC$, $I$ is the in-center and $AI$ is extended to meet the circumcircle at $D$.

$\angle DIC= \frac{A}{2}+\frac{C}{2}=\frac{A+C}{2}=90^o-\frac{B}{2}$

$$\implies \frac{IC}{\sin B}=\frac{CD}{\sin \angle DIC}$$

$$\implies IC=\frac{CD \times \sin B}{\sin (90^o-\frac{B}{2})}$$

$$\implies IC=\frac{CD \times 2\sin \frac{B}{2} \cos \frac{B}{2}}{\cos\frac{B}{2}}$$

$$\implies IC=2CD \sin \frac{B}{2}    \tag{1}$$

Note that

$$\frac{CD}{\sin \frac{A}{2}} = 2R  $$

$$  \implies CD= 2R \sin \frac{A}{2}  \tag{2}$$

and
$$r=AE=IC \sin \frac{C}{2}  \tag{3}$$

$(1), (2), (3) \implies$

$$ r=4R \sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine.

Another approach, with a little less trigonometry, uses Heron's formula and the law of cosines.

Square both sides and use $\sin^2(x/2)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}$ so you want:

$$2R^2(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)(1-\cos C)=r^2$$

The law of cosines says:

$$\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc},$$ so $$1-\cos A=\frac{a^2-(b-c)^2}{2bc}=\frac{(a+b-c)(a+c-b)}{2bc}$$ and likewise for $B,C.$

Starting with the hint:

$$\Delta =2R^2\sin A\sin B\sin C.$$
Multiply by $4R\Delta$, and use the law of sines:

$$4R\Delta^2=\Delta abc$$

Use Heron's formula on the left and $\Delta=rs$ on the right to get:

$$4Rs\frac{(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}{8}=rsabc.$$

Squaring and re-arranging, we get:

$$2R^2\frac{(a^2-(b-c)^2)(b^2-(a-c)^2)(c^2-(a-b)^2)}{8a^2b^2c^2}=r^2$$

Then, by the law of cosines result above, this can be rewritten as:

$$2R^2(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)(1-\cos C)=r^2$$

Which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather simple geometrical approach that does not use the hint

Let the incenter of the triangle be $I$. Draw a perpenduclar line from $I$ to $BC$ and call the foot of the perpendicular $D$. Now, $IB$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CBA$ and $\triangle DBI$ is a right-angled triangle, thus,
$$ \cot\frac{B}{2} = \frac{BD}{ID} = \frac{BD}{r} \implies BD = r \cot\frac{B}{2}  $$
Similarly
$$ \cot\frac{C}{2} = \frac{CD}{ID} = \frac{CD}{r} \implies CD = r \cot\frac{C}{2}$$
Now
$$\begin{align}
BC &= BD + CD \\
\implies a &= r \left(\cot\frac{B}{2} + \cot\frac{C}{2}\right) \\
&= r \left( \frac{\cos\frac{B}{2}}{\sin\frac{B}{2}} + \frac{\cos\frac{C}{2}}{\sin\frac{C}{2}}\right) \\
&= r \left( \frac{\sin\frac{B+C}{2}}{\sin\frac{B}{2} \sin\frac{C}{2}} \right) \\
\implies 2R\sin A \left(\sin\frac{B}{2} \sin\frac{C}{2} \right) &= r \sin\frac{\pi - A}{2} \\
\implies 2R \left( 2\sin\frac{A}{2} \cos\frac{A}{2} \right) \sin\frac{B}{2} \sin\frac{C}{2} &= r \cos\frac{A}{2} \\
\therefore 4R \sin\frac{A}{2} \sin\frac{B}{2} \sin\frac{C}{2} &= r
\end{align}$$
Note that $\cos\dfrac{A}{2} \ne 0$ because $A \ne \pi$

Answer (score 1):

By using the area formula
$$\Delta=\sqrt{s(s-a)bc}\sin{\frac{A}{2}},$$
at each vertex of the triangle, we can have
$$\Delta^6=s^3(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(abc)^2\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}}\sin^2{\frac{B}{2}}\sin^2{\frac{C}{2}}.$$
After simplifying by Heron's formula,
$$\Delta^4=s^2(abc)^2\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}}\sin^2{\frac{B}{2}}\sin^2{\frac{C}{2}}.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand,
$$\Delta^4=\Delta^2\Delta^2=(sr)^2\left(\frac{abc}{4R}\right)^2.\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, the result follows.